# Change instruction test eax, eax to text eax, 1

Tags: disassembly, assembly, radare2, patch-reversing

I'm trying to change an instruction in assembly. Try with `test eax, eax` to `test eax, 1`. I try modify the opcodes. 
For example opcode of `test eax, eax`: `85c0`
[image]

Try to understand why is 85c0 with this table:
[image]

`85` comes from 'test', ok. But `c0` from `EB lb`? I'm a little confused how to create that opcode and how to modify and get `test eax, 1`.

Thanks, appreciate any help!

Comment: This table shows only the first byte. There has to be more on that page that allows to  say what are the next bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Great explanation @bart1e algo the page, it helps a lot!:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opcode you are interested in is `a9 01 00 00 00` standing for `test eax, 1`.

The easiest way to get the opcode of assembly instruction is just to **compile**  it and **disassemble** the result (for example using [nasm](https://www.nasm.us/) and then [objdump](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) or simply [this site](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm)) - this way you don't have to remember anything about the opcodes which are sometimes weird.

However, you want to patch 2 bytes instruction and the opcode I gave is 5 bytes. As a workaround, you can do `test al, 1` (`a8 01`), which will do the same (will do `test` only on the least significant byte of `eax`).